# Replacement char attributes in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, core-text

The @"\uFFFC" replacement character is drawn in iOS6, which does not happen in iOS5. After drawing the images in the position of these replacement characters, the small rectangle appears on top of the image.

Is it possible to avoid this situation, without changing the attribute of the CTRun? (By setting the text color to clear?)

I am following the tutorial in http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app

But instead of using the " " character I am using the replacement character (as the documentation recommends).
The problem is that, by using this character, a rectangle is displayed over the image that I am drawing (this problem happens in iOS6 only)

```
//add a space to the text so that it can call the delegate
[aString appendAttributedString:[[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\uFFFC" attributes:attrDictionaryDelegate] autorelease]];
```

Comment: Could you show some code exhibiting the problem?